# How to determine the starting address of unused memory region in operating system?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory, ram, large-data

I am working on some project related with *huge objects* in **physical memory** in Windows.
I wanted to create really big structure of data, but therefore I found some problems. 
While I am trying to allocate huge amount of data I can just create as large object as **heap** allows (it also depends on architecture of operating system). 
I am not sure if this is restricted by *private heap of thread*, or some other way.

When I was looking for how operating system places data in memory, I found out that the data is stored in some particular order. 
And here comes some questions...

If I want to create *large objects*, should I have one very *large heap region* to allocate memory inside? If so, I have to fragmentate data.
In other way, there came an idea, of **finding [starting addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqVOn.jpg) of empty regions**, and then use this unused place to put data in some *data structure*.

If this idea is possible to realize, then how it could be done?

Another question is that, do you think that list would be the best option for that sort of *huge object*? Or maybe it would be better to use another *data structure*?

Do you think that chosen *data structure* could be divided into two regions of data separately, but standing as one object?

Thanks in advance, every answer for my questions could be helpful.

Comment: Outside of assembly language and/or an OS kernel, it's not your place to know where memory you don't own is. Most OSes even go to some lengths to _keep_ you from knowing. Just allocate as much as you need and let the OS decide how to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of misconception about memory allocation here.

(1) Most operating systems do not allocate memory linearly. There usually are discontinuities in the memory mapped to a process address space.

(2) If you want to allocate a huge amount of memory, you should do it directly with the operating system; not through a heap.

Comment: Ad 1. In the meaning of "particular order", I meant that OS is deciding where to put each thing in memory space. I know it is not linear. 

Ad 2. Do you know some kind of Memory allocations which would be done directly through OS? 

I know some functions like **HeapAlloc** or **VirtualAlloc** but I wondering how I could manage it best way.

Comment: @JarosławAbram: You don't have to care whether it's linear in physical memory. If you allocate the memory all at once, it will be linear in virtual memory, and outside of kernel space, there is no useful difference.